# Try-Catch doesn't show Message Dialog box with await

Tags: c#, windows-8, try-catch

The following code successfully gets data from a web service and displays it in a Windows 8 desktop app.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:12345/api/items");

var info = new List<SampleDataGroup>();

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);

    foreach (var data in item)
    {
        var infoSect = new SampleDataGroup
        (
            (string)data.Id.ToString(),
            (string)data.Name,
            (string)"",
            (string)data.PhotoUrl,
            (string)data.Description
        );
        info.Add(infoSect);
    }
}
else
{
    MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Error");
    await dlg.ShowAsync();
}
```

This does however require an internet connection to work. The app crashes every time there is no internet connection.

How do I write a `try catch` statement in this code to display a pop up message if the network connection  doesnt work?

**EDIT:**

I am trying to use `MessageDialog` below, and this stops the app from crashing, but it doesn't bring up the message.

```
     catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageDialog err = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);

        }
```

Comment: Did you try? On a first glance, wrapping the whole code in a try/catch should work ok...

Comment: Please see the edit above, I tried that but it doesn't show the message, it does however, stop the crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you need

```
string errorMessage = string.Empty;

try 
{

  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  HttpResponseMessage response = await    
  client.GetAsync("http://localhost:12345/api/items");

  var info = new List<SampleDataGroup>();

  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);

    foreach (var data in item)
    {
        var infoSect = new SampleDataGroup
        (
            (string)data.Id.ToString(),
            (string)data.Name,
            (string)"",
            (string)data.PhotoUrl,
            (string)data.Description
        );
        info.Add(infoSect);
    }
  }
  else
  {
      errorMessage = "Error";
  }      
}    
catch (Exception ex)
{
  ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
}

if (errorMessage != string.Empty) 
{
  MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog(errorMessage);
  await dlg.ShowAsync();
}
```

?

Comment: It works but I get a warning on the code "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the await operator to the result of the call"

Comment: But when I do include await `await err.ShowAsync();` I get an error "cannot await in the body of a catch clause"