# Custom Exceptions and Message Dialog in Try-Catch clause

Tags: c#, async-await, try-catch, custom-exceptions, messagedialog

I develop an Universal App that need several custom exceptions to catch errors encountered when calling webservices: NoInternetAccessException, NoJSONException, UserTimeoutException, ...

Here is an example of **one of these classes**:

```
    public class NoInternetAccessException : Exception
    {
        private DateTime time;

        public DateTime Time { get { return time; } }

        public NoInternetAccessException(string message, DateTime time) 
            : base(message)
        {
            this.time = time;
        }
    }
```

I catch these exceptions at several places:

in a **JSONParser**, where I create the URI and call the Client.GetAsync method:

```
    ...
    try
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(Timeout);
        response = await client.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).AsTask(cts.Token);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return response;                   
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        if ((_currentRetries == MaxRetries)
            throw new UserTimeoutException("User Timeout Exception", DateTime.Now);
        else
            _currentRetries++;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (e.HResult == -2147012889)
            throw new WrongUrlException("Wrong URL Exception", e, DateTime.Now);
    }
    ...
```

in a **WebService helper** where I manage all the webservices calls:

```
    public static async Task<Infos> GetInfos(String url, List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> parameters, String protocol)
    {        
        var response = await JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(url, parameters, "");
        Infos infos = new Infos();

        try
        {
            WsResponse wsResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Infos>(response.ToString());
            infosCe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Infos>(wsResponse.data.ToString());
            return infosCe;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new DeserializeException("Deserialize exception", e, DateTime.Now, "Infos");
        }
    }
```

All these exceptions are **finally catched by the ViewModels**, after the call to the webservices:

```
    private async Task<Infos> WebServiceGetInfos()
    {
        ...
        try
        {
            Infos infos = await WebServices.GetInfos(url, parameters, "");
            return infosCe;
        }

        // Exceptions
        catch (DeserializeException dE)
        {
            ExceptionsMsgboxHelper.MsgboxDeserialize(dE);
            return null;
        }
        catch (NoInternetAccessException niaE)
        {
            ExceptionsMsgboxHelper.MsgboxNoInternetAccess(niaE, true, "");
            return null;
        }
        catch (NoJSONException njsonE)
        {
            ExceptionsMsgboxHelper.MsgboxNoJSON(njsonE);
            return null;
        }
        ...
    }
```

I would like so that each exception calls the **ExceptionsMsgboxHelper** helper, that shows a specific Message Dialog per exception:

```
    public async static void MsgboxNoJSON(NoJSONException njsonE)
    {
        Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog msgbox =
        new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("There is a problem when retrieving data. If the problem persists, please contact your administrator.",
            "Unexpected data received");
        await msgbox.ShowAsync();
    }
```

***=> But this doesn't work, as the Message Dialog doesn't work in a Try-Catch clause...***

I also look for a solution on stackoverflow:

[Message dialog not showing in catch clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199410/message-dialog-not-showing-in-catch-clause)

[Try-Catch doesn't show Message Dialog box with await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198498/try-catch-doesnt-show-message-dialog-box-with-await)

But I don't see how to adapt this solution to my case, as I use several custom exceptions:

```
    public static async Task Foo()
    {
        Exception e = null;
        try
        {
            //just something to throw an exception
            int a = 0;
            int n = 1 / a;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            e = ex;
        }
        if (e != null)
            await ShowDialog();
    }
```

***=> Is it a better way to do this than duplicate this code to each custom exception?***

```
    ...
    DeserializeException dEx = null;
    NoInternetAccessException niaEx = null;
    NoJSONException njsonEx = null;
    try
    {
        Infos infos = await WebServices.GetInfos(url, parameters, "");
        return infosCe;
    }

    // Exceptions
    catch (DeserializeException dE)
    {
        dEx = de;
    }
    catch (NoInternetAccessException niaE)
    {
        niaEx = niaE;
    }
    catch (NoJSONException njsonE)
    {
        njsonEx=njsonE;
    }
    ...
    if (dEx != null)
    {
        ExceptionsMsgboxHelper.MsgboxDeserialize(dEx);
        return null;
    }
    if (niaEx != null)
    {
        ExceptionsMsgboxHelper.MsgboxNoInternetAccess(niaEx);
        return null;
    }
    if (njsonEx != null)
    {
        ExceptionsMsgboxHelper.MsgboxNoJSON(njsonEx);
        return null;
    }
    ...
```

***=> It doesn't seem to be powerfull or maintainable...***

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved my problem by catching a generic exception and testing it:

```
    ...
    Exception ex = null;
    try
    {
        Infos infos = await WebServices.GetInfos(url, parameters, "");
        return infosCe;
    }

    // Exceptions
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ex = e;
    }
    if (ex != null)
    {
        if (ex is DeserializeException)
        {
            DeserializeException dE = (DeserializeException)ex;
            ExceptionsMsgboxHelper.MsgboxDeserialize(dE);
        }
        if (ex is NoInternetAccessException)
        {
            NoInternetAccessException niaE = (NoInternetAccessException)ex;
            ExceptionsMsgboxHelper.MsgboxNoInternetAccess(niaE);
        }
        if (ex is NoJSONException)
        {
            NoJSONException njsonE = (NoJSONException)ex;
            ExceptionsMsgboxHelper.MsgboxNoJSON(njsonE);
        }
        ...
    }
    return null;
```

***=> If you think there is a better way to do this, please indicate me.***